# Why use and on if?

Tags: lua

Why use

```lua
if var == 1 and var2 == 1 then
end
```

if I can just make

```lua
if var == 1 then
       if var2 == 1 then
       end
end
```

Comment: I assume you intended both snippets to be equivalent. I've edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Technically speaking, there is no difference, aside from that the former saves you from nesting one more level.

Comment: You can do that if you want. What about `if (var == 1 and var2 == 1) or var3 == 1 then` ?

Answer (score 2):

Both are valid, and they do exactly the same thing. You could just as easily ask why one should use nested `if`s when you can use `and`.

The version with `and` is more succinct, and I'd probably prefer it in this case. But in practice, it's going to be part of a larger program, and the structure of that program (which we can't see here) may suggest that one form or the other is clearer.

If there are things you want to do if `var == 1`, regardless of the value of `var2`, then the nested `if`s are probably the way to go:

```lua
if var == 1 then
    if var2 == 1 then
        do_something
    end
    do_something_else
end
```

If `var` being equal to 1 and `var1` being equal to 1 are somehow logically tied together, then it makes sense to put them into the same condition with `and`.

You should write code that is:

- Reasonably succinct (but not abbreviated to the point of obscurity)
- Clear to the target audience
- Maintainable, so it can be changed as requirements change without major surgery.

There's not enough information in your example to tell how it should be structured. (And names like `var` and `var1`, while they're ok for examples, should rarely be used in real-world code.)